# Drop down of values in on column based on another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data that looks like this:

```
Category    ProductName    ABunchOfOtherFields....
--------------------------------------------------
Drink       Soda
Drink       Milk
Drink       Water
Fruit       Apple
Fruit       Orange
Fruit       Banana
```

I'd like to make 2 drop downs, one for the drinks and one for the fruits.  So far I have been using the data validation tool, but I cannot figure out how to filter the values of one column based on another column.

EDIT:

There are more columns in this data and the sheet this data sits on is populated from a db connection, i.e. I cannot change the data here, and I will not know how many rows are in each category, so manually selecting them is out of the question.

I also am not looking for cascading drop downs.  On another sheet, I have pre-selected categories and I want to generate a group of products with those categories.

```
Beverage: [Dropdown of all drinks] [Fields populated from the selected drink]
Snack:    [Dropdown of all fruits] [Fields populated from the selected fruit]
etc...
```

The names of the categories will be different than the names of the row headers for each selection, which is also out of my control.  So exactly what I am looking for is how to generate each of these drop downs with a filtered list from the data sheet that requires looking at the category field.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to get only `Apple`, `Orange` and `Banana` when you pick `Fruit` in the first dropdown, then I think the simplest solution would be what follows. Note that the first dropdown should have been already created. Let's say that it's in cell C1:

1. Create a named range for each catergory. To create a named range, you have two quick ways:

   - Go to "Formulas" > "Define Name", pick a name, and select the range. In your example, you would select `Soda`, `Milk`, `Water` and name the range as `Drink`. Repeat with `Fruit` for the next one.
   - Select the first range (`Soda`, `Milk`, `Water`) and in the name box (the box to the right of the formula bar), type in the name of the named range, for this instance `Drink` and repeat for the others.
2. In the cell you want to place the second dropdown, use a data validation and pick "List" and in the 'Source', use the formula:

   ```
   =INDIRECT(C1)
   ```

   This will pick the appropriate named range and get only the Products that corresponds to the relevant category, of course, if the naming of ranges was properly done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am not looking for cascading drop downs and I cannot use named ranges (I think).  Please check my edits to the question for more information.

Comment: @NickLarsen Okay, I understand better now. I've been trying to think about a way to do that but I'm still not quite sure how to do that; and not being able to use named ranges is just sad in such a situation. But one thing I wanted to ask: You have only to make the dropdown for drinks, dropdown for fruits and dropdown for [insert category] so far, right?

Comment: yes that's correct.  Currently I just have a separate sheet for each and I asked the DBA to give me different queries for each of them, but I'd prefer to keep it all on one sheet if possible.  At least the main query, so that we can get rid of these extra queries in the db.

Comment: I'm also okay with using named ranges if they can be automated, but once this spreadsheet leave my hands, it expected I wont be touching it again.